# How to disable horizontal scrolling to a Tab on Google Material Design for iOS

Tags: ios, swift, material-design, material-components

I'm having problem figuring out how to disable the horizontal scrolling of the Tab bar from Google Material Design for iOS. I'm planning to make a fixed tab bar with 3 tabs options.

Maybe someone can help me. Thank you in advance.

Sample Code:

```
import UIKit
import MaterialComponents
import ChameleonFramework

class ViewController: UIViewController, MDCTabBarDelegate {


  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = .white
    navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
    setupView()
  }

  let tabBarContainer: MDCTabBar = {

    let tabBar = MDCTabBar()

    tabBar.barTintColor = .white

    tabBar.items = [
      UITabBarItem(title: "All Activities", image: nil, tag: 0),
      UITabBarItem(title: "Bookmark", image: nil, tag: 0),
      UITabBarItem(title: "My Journal", image: nil, tag: 0)
    ]

    tabBar.itemAppearance = .titledImages
    tabBar.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleBottomMargin]
    tabBar.sizeToFit()

    tabBar.tintColor = UIColor.rgb(red: 12, green: 82, blue: 143)
    tabBar.selectedItemTintColor = UIColor.rgb(red: 12, green: 82, blue: 143)
    tabBar.unselectedItemTintColor = .lightGray

    return tabBar
  }()

  func setupView() {
    view.addSubview(tabBarContainer)
    view.addConstraintsWithFormat("H:|[v0]|", views: tabBarContainer)
    view.addConstraintsWithFormat("V:|[v0(48)]", views: tabBarContainer)
  }
}
```

[Actual sample of the issue on simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V39kW.gif)

Comment: Please check this, its resolve your problem :- https://github.com/PageMenu/PageMenu

Comment: @Rashwan L

Thank you for the help. 
I appreciate it. But I'm afraid I can't use the PageMenu for now. I want to figure out how it work using Google MDC.

Answer (score 2):

May be I'm late, but I could achieve that thru

```
tabBar.alignment = .justified
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this if available :
In tabBarContainer

```
tabBar.scrollView.bounces = NO;
```

for swift 3.0 and above

```
tabBar.scrollView.bounces = false
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately it didn't work. But again, thank you for helping. :)

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

`MDCTabBar` scrolling happens when you set its alignment (`MDCTabBarAlignment`) as :

`.leading`, `.center` or `.centerSelected` and the tabs do not fit in the given frame.

If you set it as `.justified`, items will be shrinked to fit into the frame.

```
myMdcTabBar.alignment = .justified
```